# Using PHP to download file from HTTP

Tags: php, download

I am trying to use PHP to download a file from this link http://192.168.1.9:8080/savegame4 but it gives me an error saying

> file_get_contents(http://192.168.1.9:8080/savegame4): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404

The link is a direct link to the download as there is no other link I can get

This is my code below.

```
$url = 'http://192.168.1.9:8080/savegame4'; 
  
$file_name = basename($url); 

if(file_put_contents( $file_name,file_get_contents($url))) { 
    echo "File downloaded successfully"; 
} 
else { 
    echo "File downloading failed."; 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried visiting the link on your browser to see that there's something there to download? A 404 error suggests that the content doesn't exist.

Comment: _Obvious qirst question_ Do you have a web server running on you local network with ip address 192.168.1.9 listening on port 8080?

Comment: Yes when i visit the link it downloads a file for me right away. So ones i click the link it opens and closes a tab in the browser and starts downloading file